# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, categorical-data

i am trying to make boxplot for my categorical variables and i have this error :
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

this is my code :pls see attached pic
what should i do ?
thanks in advance

[image]

i tried to change the name of the variable but it didn't works

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing the "plt" variable? Please share the whole code in situations like that.

But trying to solve your problem, the correct syntax to import "plt" should be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

if you do this way, you can call

```py
plt.title('trans and price')
```

with no errors.